# pcl_ros in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: pcl, cmake, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to work with pcl_ros in a package but I don't know how to include it in the CMakeLists.txt file.
I tried to use:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED
    roscpp
    sensor_msgs
    pcl_ros
)
```

Unfortunately it is not working. I get an error when compiling.

I am using ROS Hydro (catkin system) but the perception package (pcl_ros) was downloaded manually and is inside my workspace.

I would appreciate if you can help me.

[EDIT]

```
CMake Error at /home/summitxl/catkin_ws/build/Compilados/pcl_msgs-hydro-devel/cmake/pcl_msgs-genmsg.cmake:53 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "pcl_msgs_generate_messages_cpp"
  because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing
  target is a custom target created in source directory
  "/home/summitxl/catkin_ws/src/pcl2_to_scan".  See documentation for policy
  CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:299 (include)
  Compilados/pcl_msgs-hydro-devel/CMakeLists.txt:14 (generate_messages)    

CMake Error at /home/summitxl/catkin_ws/build/Compilados/pcl_msgs-hydro-devel/cmake/pcl_msgs-genmsg.cmake:100 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "pcl_msgs_generate_messages_lisp"
  because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing
  target is a custom target created in source directory
  "/home/summitxl/catkin_ws/src/pcl2_to_scan".  See documentation for policy
  CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:299 (include)
  Compilados/pcl_msgs-hydro-devel/CMakeLists.txt:14 (generate_messages)


CMake Error at /home/summitxl/catkin_ws/build/Compilados/pcl_msgs-hydro-devel/cmake/pcl_msgs-genmsg.cmake:147 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "pcl_msgs_generate_messages_py"
  because another target with the same name already exists.  The existing
  target is a custom target created in source directory
  "/home/summitxl/catkin_ws/src/pcl2_to_scan".  See documentation for policy
  CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:299 (include)
  Compilados/pcl_msgs-hydro-devel/CMakeLists.txt:14 (generate_messages)

CMake Error at /home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/extras.cmake:60 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "pcl_ros_gencfg" because another
  target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom
  target created in source directory
  "/home/summitxl/catkin_ws/src/pcl2_to_scan".  See documentation for policy
  CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  perception_pcl-hydro-devel/pcl_ros/CMakeLists.txt:43 (generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options)

CMake Warning at navigation-hydro-devel/costmap_2d/CMakeLists.txt:143 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findgtest.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "gtest", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gtest" with any of
  the following names:

    gtestConfig.cmake
    gtest-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gtest" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gtest_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "gtest"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191170/pcl_ros-in-cmakelists.txt/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-08-25**:
What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, from the error messages it looks like the targets in your custom package `pcl2_to_scan` are conflicting with `pcl_msgs`. Which leads me to believe that you have not only `pcl_ros`, but the whole `perception_pcl` stack inside your workspace.

If you need to modify and overlay some part of `pcl_ros`:

- clean your build folders (`rm -rf build devel`)
- install `ros-hydro-perception-pcl` so that all the dependencies are met
- clone `https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl` to your workspace, you can get rid of the `perception_pcl` metapackage.
- try to build the workspace with only `pcl_ros` inside of it, remove all your custom code for now.
- once that builds successfully, and it should, try `roscd pcl_ros` to make sure that rospack is using the overlay instead of the system installation
- track down the naming conflict in `pcl2_to_scan` CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-08-25**:
I solved it by changing my perception_pcl package from catkin_ws to ros_catkin_ws.
Thank you